# Installing a Diamond Monster 3D II 3dfx Voodoo2 8MB PCI on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

Does anyone know how to get a Diamond Monster 3D II 3dfx Voodoo2 8MB PCI graphics card to work with Windows 7?

I have tried searching for drivers, but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

There are few examples there: http://www.3dfxzone.it/enboard/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=1839

Looks like it's possible.